$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x(y - x^2 + 2), y(0) = 1$ using Picard's successive approximation
I was solving this initial value problem $\frac{dy}{dx} = x(y - x^2 + 2), y(0) = 1$ and I wasn't getting any pattern out of it, following is the value at each iteration i got;
$$\begin{aligned}
y_1(x) &= \frac{-x^4}{2^2} + \frac{3x^2}{2} + 1 \\
y_2(x) &= \frac{-x^6}{2^3\times 3} + \frac{x^4}{2^3} + \frac{3x^2}{2} + 1 \\
y_3(x) &= \frac{-x^8}{2^6\times 3} + \frac{x^6}{2^4\times 3} + \frac{x^4}{2^3} + \frac{3x^2}{2} + 1 \\ y_4(x) &= \frac{-x^{10}}{2^7\times 3 \times 5} + \frac{x^8}{2^7\times 3} + \frac{x^6}{2^4\times 3} + \frac{x^4}{2^3} + \frac{3x^2}{2} + 1 \\ y_5(x) &= \frac{-x^{12}}{2^4\times 3^2 \times 5} + \frac{x^{10}}{2^8\times 3 \times 5} + \frac{x^8}{2^7\times 3} + \frac{x^6}{2^4\times 3} + \frac{x^4}{2^3} + \frac{3x^2}{2} + 1
\end{aligned}$$
I wasn't able to get any pattern so I just wrote it in it's prime factors

This is linear, you can use integrating factors. Via partial integration you should be able to resolve any of the occuring integrals.

@LutzLehmann You are correct ,I can solve it normally, but I am supposed to solve using Picard's successive approximation method, I need help in that

Except for the $x^2$ term, the others should be $x^{2n}/(2^n n!)$.

Picard iteration is
$$y_{n+1}(t)=y_0+\int_{t_0}^tf(s,y_n(s))\mathrm ds$$
Where $y_0$ is the constant function $t\mapsto y(t_0)$.
Taking $t_0=0$, $y(t_0)=y_0=1$, $f(a,b)=ab-a^3+2a$, we get
$$y_{n+1}(t)=1+\int_0^t sy_n(s)-s^3+2s~\mathrm ds=1-\frac{t^4}{4}+t^2+\int_0^tsy_n(s)\mathrm ds$$
Now let's iterate. We get
$$y_1(t)=1-\frac{t^4}{4}+t^2+\int_0^ts\mathrm ds\\=1+\frac{3}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{4}t^4$$
Next step:
$$y_2(t)=1-\frac{1}{4}t^4+t^2+\int_0^t s\left(1+\frac{3}{2}s^2-\frac{s^4}{4}\right)\mathrm ds \\ =1+\frac{3}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{8}t^4-\frac{1}{24}t^6$$
Next step:
$$y_3(t)=1-\frac{1}{4}t^4+t^2+\int_0^ts\left(1+\frac{3}{2}s^2+\frac{1}{8}s^4-\frac{1}{24}s^6\right)\mathrm ds \\ =1+\frac{3}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{8}t^4+\frac{1}{48}t^6-\frac{1}{192}t^8$$
Let's do one more for good measure:
$$y_4(t)=1-\frac{1}{4}t^4+t^2+\int_0^ts\left(1+\frac{3}{2}s^2+\frac{1}{8}s^4+\frac{1}{48}s^6-\frac{1}{192}s^8\right)\mathrm ds \\ =1+\frac{3}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{8}t^4+\frac{1}{48}t^6+\frac{1}{384}t^8-\frac{1}{1920}t^{10}$$
One might notice that
$$8=2^22! \\ 48=2^33! \\ 384=2^44! \\ 1920=2^{5-1}5!$$
From this we make the guess that
$$y_n(t)=1+\frac{3}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n!}t^{2(n+1)}+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{2^kk!}t^{2k}$$
Exercise for you: Can you use induction to verify that this is correct?
Second exercise for you: Demonstrate, from this formula, that $y_n(t)\to t^2+\mathrm e^{t^2/2}$ pointwise for all $t\in\mathbb R$.
